# Array replacing not working

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, generic-list

I've an array list like this:

```
Dim valori As New List(Of String)
```

I would replace the last cell of the array, so I make this code:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To valori.Count - 1
                        If valori.Count <> 0 Then
                            item = valori(x).Split(",")
                            Dim prop = item(4)
                            Dim decimalVal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(prop)
                            If prop <> 0 Then
                                valori(x).Replace(prop, "14") 'should update the array content
                                MessageBox.Show(valori(x))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next x
```

How you can see, my array is characterized by String, so in the first time I split the array, and get the last cell (4). I save this cell in decimalVal variable then convert this value into decimal.
At this point I compare the value of decimalVal with 0 (recursive function). 
I find myself inside a for loop with "x" index, so I log to valori(x) index and then replace the prop value with 14, I put 14 to try, but I would simply decrease the value...
Apparently not the replacement is successful and the array remains unchanged, what is wrong?

Comment: `If valori.Count <> 0 Then` is redundant - this condition is always `True`. If `valori.Count = 0` the loop will never execute. What's the contents of `valori`? What does your code produce? What did you expect?

Comment: `valori(x).Replace(prop, "14")` this is also wrong.  Strings are immutable (cant be changed); a new one has to be created with the new contents.  `valori(x) = valori(x).Replace(prop, "14")`.  `valori` is also not an array or array list.  It is a List or more generally, a Collection

Comment: valori.count contains the elements of an array.
I expect that every element of the array is split and the fourth cell is decreased the number of state, I do it by replacing 15 with 14 and so on, but this does not happen.

Comment: valori(x) = valori(x).Replace(prop, System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(prop)) give me this error message: AmbiguosMatchException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strings are immutable](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/) meaning that calling `Replace` on a string doesn't update the string in question, it returns a new string. So this line:

```
valori(x).Replace(prop, "14")
```

Won't replace the string as it returns the replaced string. You need to assign this back to the original string:

```
valori(x) = valori(x).Replace(prop, "14")
```